# Change UITableViewController background color under the table

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'am trying to change the color under the UITableViewController's cells but I can't do it. (gray section on screenshot after the swipe down of table)
[image]

I tried with:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

and:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

I don't find any options on storyboard
Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set tableview background view first to change tableview backgroundcolor.

```
let view = UIView()
view.frame = self.tableView.frame
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.tableView.backgroundView = view
```